# Programming pattern for filtering SQL database contents in several different ways

Tags: php, sql, api

I'm working on a project where we have a table in a SQL database which will potentially contain a relatively large number (hundreds of thousands) of rows.

This project is written in PHP, and is using PDO to access my database. In this project, to implement "reports" and various things, I need to be able to select rows out of this table, filtering the data by different properties, depending on what context I'm going to be displaying the data in.

I'm curious what a very well-performing design for this type of situation would be. I've thought of the following options for this, but I don't really like any of them:

- Write a separate query (i.e. API function) for each different filtering technique. This seems undesirable because I'll be duplicating 90% of the SQL in each function, and it's hard to maintain (e.g., if I need to alter / fix one of my queries, I now need to alter / fix ALL of them, instead of just one).
- Provide a single API function which retrieves an unfiltered list of rows, and then filter them in my application, instead of using SQL. This is undesirable because it's wasting a lot of effort processing rows my application doesn't care about.
- Write a single function with a single query, with various optional parameters which, if provided would alter the `WHERE` clause of the query. This is probably the best option I have so far, but I'm still not sure I like it because it would mean having a function with a really weird signature, and having a bunch of ternary statements to alter the `WHERE` clause depending on whether or not the arguments were given.

Are there one or more generally accepted programming patterns for designing an API which provides this type of functionality?

Comment: why not write your filters as views. that way you simply point your app at the views, and can change the back-end filtering any way you want without affecting the consumers of the data.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is functionally different from writing a separate API function for each filtering technique, since at the end of the day I have a totally separate query for each different case, which seems to not be very maintainable.

Comment: Maybe some example queries so we can see the similarities / differences, since 90% is the same?

Comment: So, in each different case I will be retrieving the same columns (about 15 columns), and joining the same tables (there are about 10 I have to join regardless of what filtering I need). The queries would be identical except for the "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use an ORM to have something along the lines of

```
ORM::getTable('api')->getBaseQuery('get')->filterSomething()->execute();
```

and have the getBaseQuery returning the part without the WHERE and multiple filterSomething adding your conditions to the base.

If you just use objects, do the same thing by putting your basequery in base class or interface, and have your specialized queries implementing/ inheriting your base query with your condition.

if you use plain php, i would go with the strategy pattern:
http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html (you have to scroll they don't offer anchors there unfortunately).

Comment: So, this is basically just an abstracted version of retrieving all of the data and then filtering it in PHP, instead of using SQL? How does this account for the fact that, in my case, retrieving rows (i.e. `getBaseQuery`) will need to do a not-insignificant amount of processing of the data, which is then wasted by throwing away entries in `filterSomething()`?

Comment: no, the basequery would just return the sql string not execute it. Filtersomething would add the where, and execute, then fires the sql query.

Comment: It would be more like a wrapper around what Andrew suggested.

Comment: Ah, I see, I actually do like that more, because having a library with unit tests which assembles SQL queries seems nicer in a few ways than doing raw string manipulation.

Comment: good luck for your project !

Answer (score 1):

If all you're modifying is the where clause, you could store the initial part of the query in as a constant or such in one object (or a property, etc), then have a function for each query that grabs the first part of the query and appends on your where clause.

Comment: This would definitely work, but I'm slightly wary because it seems like a significant number of people hold the opinion that doing string manipulation with SQL is something that should be avoided. Maybe I should just deal with it?

Comment: How you send the query is not relevant.  Your separate functions can use paramterized sql and then the actual parameter values, as opposed to building a full SQL string